# File Upload with Server in safe_mode

Tags: php, uploads

When I try to upload an image to a post, I get an error:

"The uploaded file could not be moved to /home/httpd/xxxx/xxxx/xxx/wp/wp-content/uploads."

My server is set up in safe_mode - is that the problem? What can I do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing to do with safe_mode
try this:

- login to your ftp
- make your wp-content folder 755
- inside wp-content create a new folder called "uploads", make it 777 (755 should also work)
- inside the control admin panel, go to settings>miscellaneous and on the first line enter "wp-content/uploads" as where your uploads will go to.

Save and go try !

Comment: I saw these instructions elsewhere online. Although they probably generally work, this does not work for me. The uploads folder is created already.